# Mapping integral values to other integral values

Tags: c++, algorithm, unicode, codepages

I'm mapping the characters in the archaic [IBM Code Page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) to 16-bit UCS2 codes. Going to UCS2 is a fairly straight forward process:

```
const unsigned short ibm437_to_ucs[] = { 0x0000, 0x0001, ..., 0x2320, 0x00f7 };
...
return ibm437_to_ucs[ibm_code];
```

However the UCS codes are not sequential, so I've opted out of writing a comparable array going the other direction. Is there a better way than simply looping over the original array for each character UCS character?

```
for(int i = 0; i < IBM437_MAX /* 0xff */; i++)
{
    if(ibm437_to_ucs[i] == ucs_code)
        return i;
}
return '?';
```

Comment: Subdivide the set into subsets with contiguous codes in both places?

Comment: To add to what @AlexeyFrunze has said, if you end up with more than a handful of ranges you could use binary search to find the one.

Comment: I overlooked C++ tag on your question. 
In C:
Try LRU cache. Basically it's an "array of pointers to link-list holding the value". Index to this array can be using some algorithm, and once you find the element in link list, then move it to head so that the next lookup for same element becomes faster.

-----
In C++, the best would be to rely on STL. Best is to use "vector" or "Map".

Comment: I'd trap the ascii subset and use a `map<>` for the rest.

Comment: It turns out that an std::map is two orders of magnitude slower than Mr. Frunze's binary search.

Comment: Just curious, what is the speed difference like between your original solution and Alexey Frunze's binary search?

Comment: I had a mistake that was slowing down the stl map tests, but its still a hog. The loop in the OP is outrageously slow. So slow that the benchmark process is hung up trying to process it. Here's some results for 7.5 million iterations of 128 IBM437 characters (960 million lookups): `bsearch w/ callback: 712 ms | bsearch /w inline: 691 ms | stl map: 13300 ms | original loop: forever.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it in C (and after minor changes C++ as well) using table look ups and binary search:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// conversion tables are based on
// http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT

const unsigned short cp437hi_utf16[128] =
{
  0x00c7, 0x00fc, 0x00e9, 0x00e2, 0x00e4, 0x00e0, 0x00e5, 0x00e7,
  0x00ea, 0x00eb, 0x00e8, 0x00ef, 0x00ee, 0x00ec, 0x00c4, 0x00c5,
  0x00c9, 0x00e6, 0x00c6, 0x00f4, 0x00f6, 0x00f2, 0x00fb, 0x00f9,
  0x00ff, 0x00d6, 0x00dc, 0x00a2, 0x00a3, 0x00a5, 0x20a7, 0x0192,
  0x00e1, 0x00ed, 0x00f3, 0x00fa, 0x00f1, 0x00d1, 0x00aa, 0x00ba,
  0x00bf, 0x2310, 0x00ac, 0x00bd, 0x00bc, 0x00a1, 0x00ab, 0x00bb,
  0x2591, 0x2592, 0x2593, 0x2502, 0x2524, 0x2561, 0x2562, 0x2556,
  0x2555, 0x2563, 0x2551, 0x2557, 0x255d, 0x255c, 0x255b, 0x2510,
  0x2514, 0x2534, 0x252c, 0x251c, 0x2500, 0x253c, 0x255e, 0x255f,
  0x255a, 0x2554, 0x2569, 0x2566, 0x2560, 0x2550, 0x256c, 0x2567,
  0x2568, 0x2564, 0x2565, 0x2559, 0x2558, 0x2552, 0x2553, 0x256b,
  0x256a, 0x2518, 0x250c, 0x2588, 0x2584, 0x258c, 0x2590, 0x2580,
  0x03b1, 0x00df, 0x0393, 0x03c0, 0x03a3, 0x03c3, 0x00b5, 0x03c4,
  0x03a6, 0x0398, 0x03a9, 0x03b4, 0x221e, 0x03c6, 0x03b5, 0x2229,
  0x2261, 0x00b1, 0x2265, 0x2264, 0x2320, 0x2321, 0x00f7, 0x2248,
  0x00b0, 0x2219, 0x00b7, 0x221a, 0x207f, 0x00b2, 0x25a0, 0x00a0
};

const unsigned long utf16_cp437hi[128] =
{
  0xff00a0, 0xad00a1, 0x9b00a2, 0x9c00a3,
  0x9d00a5, 0xa600aa, 0xae00ab, 0xaa00ac,
  0xf800b0, 0xf100b1, 0xfd00b2, 0xe600b5,
  0xfa00b7, 0xa700ba, 0xaf00bb, 0xac00bc,
  0xab00bd, 0xa800bf, 0x8e00c4, 0x8f00c5,
  0x9200c6, 0x8000c7, 0x9000c9, 0xa500d1,
  0x9900d6, 0x9a00dc, 0xe100df, 0x8500e0,
  0xa000e1, 0x8300e2, 0x8400e4, 0x8600e5,
  0x9100e6, 0x8700e7, 0x8a00e8, 0x8200e9,
  0x8800ea, 0x8900eb, 0x8d00ec, 0xa100ed,
  0x8c00ee, 0x8b00ef, 0xa400f1, 0x9500f2,
  0xa200f3, 0x9300f4, 0x9400f6, 0xf600f7,
  0x9700f9, 0xa300fa, 0x9600fb, 0x8100fc,
  0x9800ff, 0x9f0192, 0xe20393, 0xe90398,
  0xe403a3, 0xe803a6, 0xea03a9, 0xe003b1,
  0xeb03b4, 0xee03b5, 0xe303c0, 0xe503c3,
  0xe703c4, 0xed03c6, 0xfc207f, 0x9e20a7,
  0xf92219, 0xfb221a, 0xec221e, 0xef2229,
  0xf72248, 0xf02261, 0xf32264, 0xf22265,
  0xa92310, 0xf42320, 0xf52321, 0xc42500,
  0xb32502, 0xda250c, 0xbf2510, 0xc02514,
  0xd92518, 0xc3251c, 0xb42524, 0xc2252c,
  0xc12534, 0xc5253c, 0xcd2550, 0xba2551,
  0xd52552, 0xd62553, 0xc92554, 0xb82555,
  0xb72556, 0xbb2557, 0xd42558, 0xd32559,
  0xc8255a, 0xbe255b, 0xbd255c, 0xbc255d,
  0xc6255e, 0xc7255f, 0xcc2560, 0xb52561,
  0xb62562, 0xb92563, 0xd12564, 0xd22565,
  0xcb2566, 0xcf2567, 0xd02568, 0xca2569,
  0xd8256a, 0xd7256b, 0xce256c, 0xdf2580,
  0xdc2584, 0xdb2588, 0xdd258c, 0xde2590,
  0xb02591, 0xb12592, 0xb22593, 0xfe25a0
};

unsigned short Cp437toUtf16(unsigned char c)
{
  if (c < 0x80)
    return c;
  return cp437hi_utf16[c - 0x80];
}

static int CompareUtf16toCp437(const void* pv1, const void* pv2)
{
  const unsigned long *pl1 = pv1, *pl2 = pv2;
  unsigned long v1 = *pl1 & 0xFFFF, v2 = *pl2 & 0xFFFF;

  if (v1 > v2)
    return +1;

  if (v1 < v2)
    return -1;

  return 0;
}

int Utf16toCp437(unsigned long cp)
{
  unsigned long* p;

  if (cp < 0x80)
    return cp;

  if (cp > 0xFFFF)
    return -1;

  p = bsearch(&cp,
              utf16_cp437hi,
              sizeof(utf16_cp437hi) / sizeof(utf16_cp437hi[0]),
              sizeof(utf16_cp437hi[0]),
              &CompareUtf16toCp437);

  if (p == NULL)
    return -1;

  return *p >> 16;
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned c;

  for (c = 0; c <= 0xFF; c++)
  {
    unsigned long cp = Cp437toUtf16(c);
    int c2 = Utf16toCp437(cp);

    printf("0x%02X -> 0x%04lX -> 0x%02X\n", c, cp, c2);

    if (c != c2)
    {
      puts("Failure!");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }

  puts("Success!");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/iSKrgN)):

```
0x00 -> 0x0000 -> 0x00
0x01 -> 0x0001 -> 0x01
0x02 -> 0x0002 -> 0x02
0x03 -> 0x0003 -> 0x03
0x04 -> 0x0004 -> 0x04
0x05 -> 0x0005 -> 0x05
0x06 -> 0x0006 -> 0x06
0x07 -> 0x0007 -> 0x07
0x08 -> 0x0008 -> 0x08
0x09 -> 0x0009 -> 0x09
0x0A -> 0x000A -> 0x0A
0x0B -> 0x000B -> 0x0B
0x0C -> 0x000C -> 0x0C
0x0D -> 0x000D -> 0x0D
0x0E -> 0x000E -> 0x0E
0x0F -> 0x000F -> 0x0F
0x10 -> 0x0010 -> 0x10
0x11 -> 0x0011 -> 0x11
0x12 -> 0x0012 -> 0x12
0x13 -> 0x0013 -> 0x13
0x14 -> 0x0014 -> 0x14
0x15 -> 0x0015 -> 0x15
0x16 -> 0x0016 -> 0x16
0x17 -> 0x0017 -> 0x17
0x18 -> 0x0018 -> 0x18
0x19 -> 0x0019 -> 0x19
0x1A -> 0x001A -> 0x1A
0x1B -> 0x001B -> 0x1B
0x1C -> 0x001C -> 0x1C
0x1D -> 0x001D -> 0x1D
0x1E -> 0x001E -> 0x1E
0x1F -> 0x001F -> 0x1F
0x20 -> 0x0020 -> 0x20
0x21 -> 0x0021 -> 0x21
0x22 -> 0x0022 -> 0x22
0x23 -> 0x0023 -> 0x23
0x24 -> 0x0024 -> 0x24
0x25 -> 0x0025 -> 0x25
0x26 -> 0x0026 -> 0x26
0x27 -> 0x0027 -> 0x27
0x28 -> 0x0028 -> 0x28
0x29 -> 0x0029 -> 0x29
0x2A -> 0x002A -> 0x2A
0x2B -> 0x002B -> 0x2B
0x2C -> 0x002C -> 0x2C
0x2D -> 0x002D -> 0x2D
0x2E -> 0x002E -> 0x2E
0x2F -> 0x002F -> 0x2F
0x30 -> 0x0030 -> 0x30
0x31 -> 0x0031 -> 0x31
0x32 -> 0x0032 -> 0x32
0x33 -> 0x0033 -> 0x33
0x34 -> 0x0034 -> 0x34
0x35 -> 0x0035 -> 0x35
0x36 -> 0x0036 -> 0x36
0x37 -> 0x0037 -> 0x37
0x38 -> 0x0038 -> 0x38
0x39 -> 0x0039 -> 0x39
0x3A -> 0x003A -> 0x3A
0x3B -> 0x003B -> 0x3B
0x3C -> 0x003C -> 0x3C
0x3D -> 0x003D -> 0x3D
0x3E -> 0x003E -> 0x3E
0x3F -> 0x003F -> 0x3F
0x40 -> 0x0040 -> 0x40
0x41 -> 0x0041 -> 0x41
0x42 -> 0x0042 -> 0x42
0x43 -> 0x0043 -> 0x43
0x44 -> 0x0044 -> 0x44
0x45 -> 0x0045 -> 0x45
0x46 -> 0x0046 -> 0x46
0x47 -> 0x0047 -> 0x47
0x48 -> 0x0048 -> 0x48
0x49 -> 0x0049 -> 0x49
0x4A -> 0x004A -> 0x4A
0x4B -> 0x004B -> 0x4B
0x4C -> 0x004C -> 0x4C
0x4D -> 0x004D -> 0x4D
0x4E -> 0x004E -> 0x4E
0x4F -> 0x004F -> 0x4F
0x50 -> 0x0050 -> 0x50
0x51 -> 0x0051 -> 0x51
0x52 -> 0x0052 -> 0x52
0x53 -> 0x0053 -> 0x53
0x54 -> 0x0054 -> 0x54
0x55 -> 0x0055 -> 0x55
0x56 -> 0x0056 -> 0x56
0x57 -> 0x0057 -> 0x57
0x58 -> 0x0058 -> 0x58
0x59 -> 0x0059 -> 0x59
0x5A -> 0x005A -> 0x5A
0x5B -> 0x005B -> 0x5B
0x5C -> 0x005C -> 0x5C
0x5D -> 0x005D -> 0x5D
0x5E -> 0x005E -> 0x5E
0x5F -> 0x005F -> 0x5F
0x60 -> 0x0060 -> 0x60
0x61 -> 0x0061 -> 0x61
0x62 -> 0x0062 -> 0x62
0x63 -> 0x0063 -> 0x63
0x64 -> 0x0064 -> 0x64
0x65 -> 0x0065 -> 0x65
0x66 -> 0x0066 -> 0x66
0x67 -> 0x0067 -> 0x67
0x68 -> 0x0068 -> 0x68
0x69 -> 0x0069 -> 0x69
0x6A -> 0x006A -> 0x6A
0x6B -> 0x006B -> 0x6B
0x6C -> 0x006C -> 0x6C
0x6D -> 0x006D -> 0x6D
0x6E -> 0x006E -> 0x6E
0x6F -> 0x006F -> 0x6F
0x70 -> 0x0070 -> 0x70
0x71 -> 0x0071 -> 0x71
0x72 -> 0x0072 -> 0x72
0x73 -> 0x0073 -> 0x73
0x74 -> 0x0074 -> 0x74
0x75 -> 0x0075 -> 0x75
0x76 -> 0x0076 -> 0x76
0x77 -> 0x0077 -> 0x77
0x78 -> 0x0078 -> 0x78
0x79 -> 0x0079 -> 0x79
0x7A -> 0x007A -> 0x7A
0x7B -> 0x007B -> 0x7B
0x7C -> 0x007C -> 0x7C
0x7D -> 0x007D -> 0x7D
0x7E -> 0x007E -> 0x7E
0x7F -> 0x007F -> 0x7F
0x80 -> 0x00C7 -> 0x80
0x81 -> 0x00FC -> 0x81
0x82 -> 0x00E9 -> 0x82
0x83 -> 0x00E2 -> 0x83
0x84 -> 0x00E4 -> 0x84
0x85 -> 0x00E0 -> 0x85
0x86 -> 0x00E5 -> 0x86
0x87 -> 0x00E7 -> 0x87
0x88 -> 0x00EA -> 0x88
0x89 -> 0x00EB -> 0x89
0x8A -> 0x00E8 -> 0x8A
0x8B -> 0x00EF -> 0x8B
0x8C -> 0x00EE -> 0x8C
0x8D -> 0x00EC -> 0x8D
0x8E -> 0x00C4 -> 0x8E
0x8F -> 0x00C5 -> 0x8F
0x90 -> 0x00C9 -> 0x90
0x91 -> 0x00E6 -> 0x91
0x92 -> 0x00C6 -> 0x92
0x93 -> 0x00F4 -> 0x93
0x94 -> 0x00F6 -> 0x94
0x95 -> 0x00F2 -> 0x95
0x96 -> 0x00FB -> 0x96
0x97 -> 0x00F9 -> 0x97
0x98 -> 0x00FF -> 0x98
0x99 -> 0x00D6 -> 0x99
0x9A -> 0x00DC -> 0x9A
0x9B -> 0x00A2 -> 0x9B
0x9C -> 0x00A3 -> 0x9C
0x9D -> 0x00A5 -> 0x9D
0x9E -> 0x20A7 -> 0x9E
0x9F -> 0x0192 -> 0x9F
0xA0 -> 0x00E1 -> 0xA0
0xA1 -> 0x00ED -> 0xA1
0xA2 -> 0x00F3 -> 0xA2
0xA3 -> 0x00FA -> 0xA3
0xA4 -> 0x00F1 -> 0xA4
0xA5 -> 0x00D1 -> 0xA5
0xA6 -> 0x00AA -> 0xA6
0xA7 -> 0x00BA -> 0xA7
0xA8 -> 0x00BF -> 0xA8
0xA9 -> 0x2310 -> 0xA9
0xAA -> 0x00AC -> 0xAA
0xAB -> 0x00BD -> 0xAB
0xAC -> 0x00BC -> 0xAC
0xAD -> 0x00A1 -> 0xAD
0xAE -> 0x00AB -> 0xAE
0xAF -> 0x00BB -> 0xAF
0xB0 -> 0x2591 -> 0xB0
0xB1 -> 0x2592 -> 0xB1
0xB2 -> 0x2593 -> 0xB2
0xB3 -> 0x2502 -> 0xB3
0xB4 -> 0x2524 -> 0xB4
0xB5 -> 0x2561 -> 0xB5
0xB6 -> 0x2562 -> 0xB6
0xB7 -> 0x2556 -> 0xB7
0xB8 -> 0x2555 -> 0xB8
0xB9 -> 0x2563 -> 0xB9
0xBA -> 0x2551 -> 0xBA
0xBB -> 0x2557 -> 0xBB
0xBC -> 0x255D -> 0xBC
0xBD -> 0x255C -> 0xBD
0xBE -> 0x255B -> 0xBE
0xBF -> 0x2510 -> 0xBF
0xC0 -> 0x2514 -> 0xC0
0xC1 -> 0x2534 -> 0xC1
0xC2 -> 0x252C -> 0xC2
0xC3 -> 0x251C -> 0xC3
0xC4 -> 0x2500 -> 0xC4
0xC5 -> 0x253C -> 0xC5
0xC6 -> 0x255E -> 0xC6
0xC7 -> 0x255F -> 0xC7
0xC8 -> 0x255A -> 0xC8
0xC9 -> 0x2554 -> 0xC9
0xCA -> 0x2569 -> 0xCA
0xCB -> 0x2566 -> 0xCB
0xCC -> 0x2560 -> 0xCC
0xCD -> 0x2550 -> 0xCD
0xCE -> 0x256C -> 0xCE
0xCF -> 0x2567 -> 0xCF
0xD0 -> 0x2568 -> 0xD0
0xD1 -> 0x2564 -> 0xD1
0xD2 -> 0x2565 -> 0xD2
0xD3 -> 0x2559 -> 0xD3
0xD4 -> 0x2558 -> 0xD4
0xD5 -> 0x2552 -> 0xD5
0xD6 -> 0x2553 -> 0xD6
0xD7 -> 0x256B -> 0xD7
0xD8 -> 0x256A -> 0xD8
0xD9 -> 0x2518 -> 0xD9
0xDA -> 0x250C -> 0xDA
0xDB -> 0x2588 -> 0xDB
0xDC -> 0x2584 -> 0xDC
0xDD -> 0x258C -> 0xDD
0xDE -> 0x2590 -> 0xDE
0xDF -> 0x2580 -> 0xDF
0xE0 -> 0x03B1 -> 0xE0
0xE1 -> 0x00DF -> 0xE1
0xE2 -> 0x0393 -> 0xE2
0xE3 -> 0x03C0 -> 0xE3
0xE4 -> 0x03A3 -> 0xE4
0xE5 -> 0x03C3 -> 0xE5
0xE6 -> 0x00B5 -> 0xE6
0xE7 -> 0x03C4 -> 0xE7
0xE8 -> 0x03A6 -> 0xE8
0xE9 -> 0x0398 -> 0xE9
0xEA -> 0x03A9 -> 0xEA
0xEB -> 0x03B4 -> 0xEB
0xEC -> 0x221E -> 0xEC
0xED -> 0x03C6 -> 0xED
0xEE -> 0x03B5 -> 0xEE
0xEF -> 0x2229 -> 0xEF
0xF0 -> 0x2261 -> 0xF0
0xF1 -> 0x00B1 -> 0xF1
0xF2 -> 0x2265 -> 0xF2
0xF3 -> 0x2264 -> 0xF3
0xF4 -> 0x2320 -> 0xF4
0xF5 -> 0x2321 -> 0xF5
0xF6 -> 0x00F7 -> 0xF6
0xF7 -> 0x2248 -> 0xF7
0xF8 -> 0x00B0 -> 0xF8
0xF9 -> 0x2219 -> 0xF9
0xFA -> 0x00B7 -> 0xFA
0xFB -> 0x221A -> 0xFB
0xFC -> 0x207F -> 0xFC
0xFD -> 0x00B2 -> 0xFD
0xFE -> 0x25A0 -> 0xFE
0xFF -> 0x00A0 -> 0xFF
Success!
```

**UPDATE**: You could also implement the binary search inline without calling `bsearch()` and the callback function. It will speed things up, if it's something of importance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was certainly creative to pack the UCS and IBM code points together in the upper and lower words of an int. It took me a lil while to see what you'd done, since I very seldom need bitwise operation in the languages I'm accustomed to. A quick search didn't tell me, though, is `bsearch` just rolling an internal for loop, or is it non-linear?

Comment: [For, while or recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). It is non-linear, namely, logarithmic.

Comment: So, each C standard library implements it differently?

Comment: There can be minor differences, but they should be entirely transparent to the user and the function must still employ binary search and not linear search or something worse.

Comment: I've added a missing check. `Utf16toCp437()` should now reliably return -1 for code points > 0xFFFF. It was unreliable with just `& 0xFFFF`.

Comment: Thank you very much for following up.